# I have an issue, when I scroll my table view data is not according to array it showing older cell data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I have an issue when I scroll `UITableView`,  first time it shows two rows  after that when I scroll at the to 3rd it showing again first row data on third row.

I have used this code :

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"inviCell1";

        inviProfileCell *cell1 =
        (inviProfileCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell1.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        if(cell1 == nil) {
            cell1 = [[inviProfileCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;

        }

      Obj=[[ObjClass alloc]init];

      Obj=[fetchedArray objectAtIndex:0];

        UIButton *btn1 = (UIButton *)[cell1 viewWithTag:101];
        UIButton *btn2 = (UIButton *)[cell1 viewWithTag:102];
        UIButton *btn3 = (UIButton *)[cell1 viewWithTag:103];
        UIButton *btn4 = (UIButton *)[cell1 viewWithTag:104];
        UIButton *btn5 = (UIButton *)[cell1 viewWithTag:105];
        UIButton *btn6 = (UIButton *)[cell1 viewWithTag:106];

        cell1.moreBtn.tag = indexPath.row+1;
        cell1.moreBtn.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        if (inviLoadCount > indexPath.row+1) {
            cell1.moreBtn.hidden = YES;
        }else{
            cell1.moreBtn.hidden = NO;
        }

        int maxindex = (int)(6*(indexPath.row+1));
        int startIndex = (int)(6*indexPath.row);
        int counter = 1;

        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)boast_Obj.purchase_array.count);
        for (int i = startIndex; i < maxindex; i++) {                
       //  functionality....
        }
```

Is there any wrong in my code?

Comment: Add `numberOfRows` method also.

Comment: -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([tableView isEqual:_inviTableView]) {
        
        return inviLoadCount;
    }

Comment: is ur rows fixed or it will vary count .

Comment: it is not fixed its based on some condition. one more thing.  i show single row at very first time after that  there is a button in a cell when i clicked on it, it reload table and fetch data if it is moe then one ... every time when i click on that button table reloads..

Comment: When I see a `for` loop in `cellForRow(at:)` it is a code smell.  This method will get called multiple times for a given row as the table scrolls and it won't be called in row order.  Using view `tag`s is also a bad idea.  Add properties to your `UITableViewCell` class so that you can access the views directly.  Also, by convention, class names should start with an upper case letter.

Comment: ya its not good habit to use tag but right now i don't want to change this logic if is it possible to do without create code in custom cell class. pls let me know..   Thanks

Comment: mention here structure of your datasource array.

Comment: Thanks guys for response. I resolved it by declaring btn in cell class. and removing tag and did some condition it works now. as  @Paulw11  said But i want it to do using tags but for now its ok. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

It is not totally clear which methods of `UITableView` are implemented in your whole class. You should have at least the two important methods in there:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
             numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Here is also a good tutorial for [this on AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)